# Foreach Loop Through json_decode array in PHP

Tags: php, json, twitter, foreach

I am trying to foreach loop through an array but am running into trouble, I am getting "Undefined index: text"

This is the code:

> $tweets = json_decode($response,true);
>
> foreach ($tweets as $tweet) {
>
> ```
>    echo $tweet['text'];
> ```
>
> }

The JSON data looks like this:

> object(stdClass)[2]
>
> ```
>  public 'statuses' => 
>
>   array (size=15)
>
>   0 => 
>
>    object(stdClass)[3]
>
>      public 'metadata' => 
>
>        object(stdClass)[4]
>
>          ...
>
>      public 'created_at' => string 'Mon Aug 04 21:25:41 +0000 2014' (length=30)
>
>      public 'id' => float 4.9640664406701E+17
>
>      public 'id_str' => string '496406644067012608' (length=18)
>
>      public 'text' => string 'Youth is served (in big helpings): 14 Chiefs could >feature NFLs youngest OL..  #Chiefs #NFL' (length=91)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over the outer object, when you need to loop over the statuses:

```
 foreach ($tweets['statuses'] as $tweet) {
```

Comment: This gives me "trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems 'statuses' is the array so `json_decode($response->statuses,true);` and text is property of an object so `echo $tweet->text;`

Comment: the "true" makes $tweets and associative array